# Unity2D bloom doesn't work although the object emits light

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game and I want to add neon effects to certain objects. I tried using Universal Render Pipeline, however, I still can't seem to get bloom to... bloom.

I will try my best to describe what I tried before:

Before: I followed a tutorial about using Universal Render Pipeline. I made a lit 2D material, created a point light and increased its intensity. I couldn't get the bloom working so I reverted back to the built-in render pipeline.

Currently: Using the built-in render pipeline, I installed the post-processing package from the package manager. I added `Post-process Layer` and `Post-process Volume` components to the Main camera. I set up a post-processing profile and added the Bloom component to it. In the `Post-process Layer`, I set the Layer to "Glowing Object" and appropriately changed the layers of the objects I want neon effect on. I dragged the profile into the appropriate field in the `Post-process Volume`. For the objects, I made separate materials that have emission set to true. However, I still don't have a blurry effect on these said objects.

Here is the game view when the directional light is disabled (although I added a culling mask to the "Glowing Object" layer, I disabled it for clarity):

[image]

The objects GLOW, but they don't BLOOM which is very confusing to me. I apologize if I'm missing something obvious but I really tried to search around for the solution. I will now provide images of each relevant game object in case I couldn't explain it well.

The object materials:

> [image] [image]

The main camera (includes post-processing components):

> [image]

Thank you so much for your help.